# Why does Knockout.js data-bind to checkedValue overwrite observable?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, observable

I am running into an issue using the knockout mapping plugin.
I have an array of **ShippingOptions** that I data-bind to radio buttons using the checked value with the checked attribute set to another object on my view model called **ShippingChoice**.

I have a computed observable Total which is the sum of a my **SubTotal** and **ShippingChoice.Price**

When one of the radio options is selected it correctly sets ShippingChoice to the selected shipping option, but it causes the **ShippingChoice** to no longer be an observable and breaks my computed total

The console shows the  error **"Type error: Number is not a function"** because I am accessing **ShippingChoice().Price** inside my computed. Once the value is set it seems to overwrite my observable with a plain object.

I attempted to use a custom mapping to set Shipping choice as an observable but that didn't help.

Jsfiddle demo at: **http://jsfiddle.net/on3al/2dv33vor/9/**

Any insight or suggestions would be greatly appreaciated. I've been banging my head at this one too long.

**HTML**

```
      <!-- ko foreach: ShippingOptions -->
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" 
                  data-bind="checkedValue: $data ,checked: $root.ShippingChoice" /> 
            <span data-bind="text: Carrier"></span>
            <span data-bind="text: Service"></span>
            <span data-bind="money: Price"></span> 
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
         <h5 class="text-right">Subtotal <strong data-bind="money: SubTotal"></strong></h5>
         <h5 class="text-right" data-bind="money: ShippingChoice().Price">Shipping </h5>
         <h4 class="text-right">Total <strong data-bind="money: Total"></strong></h4>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
   var mapping = {
         'ShippingChoice': {
             create: function (options) {
                 return ko.observable(options.data);
             }
         }
     };

     CartViewModel = function (data) {
         var self = this;
         ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self);

         self.SubTotal = ko.computed(function () {
             var subTotal = 0;
             for (var i = 0; i < self.Items().length; i++) {
                 var item = self.Items()[i];
                 subTotal += item.Quantity() * item.Product.Price();
             }
             return subTotal;
         }, self);

         self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
             return self.SubTotal()+ self.ShippingChoice().Price;
         }, self);

         self.decreaseQty = function (item) {
             var currQty = item.Quantity();
             if (currQty > 0) {
                 item.Quantity(currQty - 1);
             }
             self.updateQty(item);
         };

         self.increaseQty = function (item) {
             var currQty = item.Quantity();
             item.Quantity(currQty + 1);
             self.updateQty(item);
         };
     };

     ko.bindingHandlers.money = {
         update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
             var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
             var positions = 2;
             var formattedValue = value.toFixed(positions);
             var finalFormatted = '$' + formattedValue;

             ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function () {
                 return finalFormatted;
             });
         },
         defaultPositions: 2,
     };

     var cartViewModel = new CartViewModel({
         "$id": "1",
             "Id": "540eb73cff622605c4f45b39",
             "Items": [{
             "$id": "2",
                 "Product": {
                 "$id": "3",
                     "Status": "In Stock",
                     "Price": 19.99,
                     "QuantityInStock": 12,
                     "Brand": "Dummy Brand",
                     "Weight": 8.0,
                     "Width": 12.0,
                     "Length": 14.0,
                     "Height": 3.0,
                     "UrlSlug": "dummy-slug",
                     "Title": "Dummy Product",
             },
                 "Quantity": 7,
         }],
             "Country": "CA",
             "PostalCode": null,
             "ShippingOptions": [{
             "$id": "4",
                 "Carrier": "USPS",
                 "Price": 22.1,
                 "Service": "FirstClassPackageInternationalService"
         }, {
             "$id": "5",
                 "Carrier": "USPS",
                 "Price": 32.85,
                 "Service": "PriorityMailInternational"
         }, {
             "$id": "6",
                 "Carrier": "USPS",
                 "Price": 46.96,
                 "Service": "ExpressMailInternational"
         }],
             "ShippingChoice": {
             "$id": "7",
                 "Carrier": "",
                 "Price": 8.0,
                 "Service": ""
         }
     });
     ko.applyBindings(cartViewModel);
```

Comment: BTW, your fiddle is missing the `updateQty` function.

Answer (score 3):

You may also solve your problem just by "copying" your ShippingOptions in mapping options:

```
var mapping = {
  'ShippingChoice': {
    create: function (options) {
      return ko.observable(options.data);
    }
  },
  copy: [ 'ShippingOptions' ]
};
```

It will result in plain object array and prices will be Numbers rather than observables.

http://jsfiddle.net/2dv33vor/12/

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it. Your mapping object should be changed just a little bit:

```
var mapping = {
    'ShippingChoice': {
        create: function (options) {
            return ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data));
        }
    }
};
```

And in your view model:

```
...
self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.SubTotal()+ self.ShippingChoice().Price(); // I've added () to the Price, since it's an observable now.
}, self);
```

The thing is when your ShippingOptions array was mapped, all it's properties were made observables. So you should make your ShippingChoice's properties observables too.

#### [Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/2dv33vor/11/)

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Total` computed from:

```
 self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.SubTotal() + self.ShippingChoice().Price;
 }, self);
```

to:

```
 self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.unwrap(self.SubTotal) + ko.unwrap(self.ShippingChoice().Price);
 }, self);
```

---

When you add a `console.log(value)` to the `money` binding handler in your original code, you see this as soon as you make a shipping choice:

```
"307.65000000000003function d(){if(0<
arguments.length)return d.Pa(c,arguments[0])&&(d.X(),c=arguments[0],d.W()),this;a.k.Jb(d);return c}"
```

This indicates an observable was concatenated to a non-observable with the `+` operator.

Your `Total` function was the only place where this could happen.